# What kind of graph is this that I have drawn?

Tags: graph-theory

My research has uncovered a graph that looks like the attached image.

Does this type of graph have a cool name that I can use in my research?

It's always acyclic.

It's always directed .

There is always one originating (root?) node, indicated at left in the drawing.

It can grow to the right with any node **except the orignating node** having any number of new nodes connected to it in the same pattern as in the drawing.
The labels can be ignored.

[[image: What kind of graph is this?[1]]

Comment: Isn't this a *rooted tree*?